# C:\Python27\Scripts\virtualenv my-proj-env –no-site-packages on windows 8 32 bit

Tags: python-2.7, virtualenv

C:\Python27\Scripts\virtualenv my-proj-env –no-site-packages

I am getting this error so many times !
i have tried to change the path but i dont know something is going wrong . what to do?

Comment: please show your error, explain more about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: thank you for response ! i am trying to make an environment for django . and i am referring to https://djangonautlostinspace.wordpress.com/2012/04/16/django-and-windows/   this site , i have done all the steps except virtualenv.. m just not able to do it

Comment: hey my problem is solved i guess ;)

Comment: python.exe -m virtualenv c:/virtualenv/env1
virtualenv --no-site-packages env1     (I have done these steps)

Comment: You can submit your answer for others :)